# Confused about ykatz article on javascript constructors and prototypes

Tags: javascript

This question is inspired [from this article by Yehuda Katz.](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)  The relevant portion is this:

> In order to facilitate object oriented programming, JavaScript allows
>   you to use a Function object as a combination of a prototype to use
>   for the new object and a constructor function to invoke:
>
> ```
> var Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
>   this.firstName = firstName;
>   this.lastName = lastName;
> }
>
> Person.prototype = {
>   toString: function() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }
> }
> ```
>
> Here, we have a single Function object that is both a constructor
>   function and an object to use as the prototype of new objects.

I am confused because it seems to me the Function object acting as the constructor and the prototype are different.  This is clear from the following console output from chrome:

[image: chrome console output]

That is, the constructor function is the function object above with two arguments: firstName and lastName; whereas the prototype is just an ordinary object that happens to have one property (toString), which in turn is defined by the separate function object `function() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }`

Am I misunderstanding what he's saying, or is the article incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is incorrect. The prototype used for new objects is the one referenced by the `.prototype` property of the constructor function at the creation time of an object, which is a separate plain object from the constructor function.

```
function Person() {

}

var a = new Person(); //a.__proto__ is assigned Person.prototype

Person.prototype = {}; //This doesn't affect a, because .__proto__ was assigned at creation time

var b = new Person(); //b.__proto__ is assigned Person.prototype, which is just the random object we created with {}
```